# Quantifiers and properties, why and when do they "commute"? An elementary perpective of "non logician"

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $x \in X, \ y \in Y, \ z \in Z$ and $w \in W$. Let $P_1(x,y), \ P_2(y,z), \ P_3(z,w)$ be some properties or sentences(for example, if $R \subseteq X \times Y$, then $P_1(x,y)$ may be $xRy$).

I can't get my head around the following fact:
Say, $x$ and $w$ are fixed. The sentence "$\exists z \in Z: \ (\exists y \in Y: P_1(x,y) \wedge P_2(y,z)) \wedge P_3(z,w)$" is true if and only if "$\exists y \in Y: P_1(x,y) \wedge (\exists z \in Z: P_2(y,z) \wedge P_3(z,w))$" is. So, they are the same.

Why is that? Sure, one recommendation would pick up a book on mathematical logic and study it. But the problem is that I'm not studying logic at all, I've just encountered the need for such a proof in a book on set theory (namely, Halmos-"Naive Set Theory"). This is not my first math book, I've studied (pure and rigorous) mathematics before, but there were no need for such "logically sophisticated" proofs. How do I understand that?

Comment: It might be easier to start simpler: do you understand why $\exists x\exists y (P(x, y))$ is the same as $\exists y\exists x(P(x, y))$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber It depends on how to interprete it. If it means $\exists (x,y) \in X \times Y: P(x,y)$, then I do. If it means $\exists x: \exists y: P(x,y)$, then I'm not sure. I thought I do, but now, when I think about it, It doesn't seem to click as easy as I would expect.

Comment: I pronounce it like that: there exist x **for which** there exists y **for which** $P(x,y)$. It feels like $y$ is dependent on $x$ by the order they are presented. How do I get the right understanding for these matters?

Comment: In the antecedent for the biconditional; the scope of the variable $y$ is only $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$. So in addition to commuting quantifiers you also can commute the $\wedge$ operator through FOL sentences.

Comment: @Jxt921 Think in terms of *witnesses*: a statement "$\exists x(P(x))$" is true if, for some $a$, $P(a)$ is true. Now let's think about $\exists x\exists y(P(x, y))$; suppose this is true. Then for some $a$, we have $\exists y(P(a, y))$; in turn, this means that for some $b$, $P(a, b)$ is true. OK, so now think about $b$ - $b$ has the property that for some $x$ (namely $x=a$), $P(x, b)$ is true. That is, $b$ satisfies "$\exists x(P(x, b))$." But this exactly means that $b$ is a witness to "$\exists y\exists x(P(x, y))$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two fundamental equivalences behind this:

1. For any formula $\varphi(x,y)$, we have that:

$\exists x \exists y \varphi(x,y) \Leftrightarrow \exists y \exists x \varphi(x,y)$

This is because both sentences say the exact same thing: there are two objects standing in some relationship as expressed by $\varphi(x,y)$. So, if you have two quantifiers of the same type (it also works for two universals) right next to each other, then you can swap them. But they have to be the same type (you can't change $\forall x \exists y$ to $\exists y \forall x$) and they have to be right next to each other (e.g you can't change $\exists x \neg \exists y$ to $\exists y \neg \exists x$)

2. For any formula $\varphi(x)$ and any formula $\psi$, where $\psi$ does not contain $x$ as a free variable, we have that:

$\psi \land \exists x \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\psi \land \varphi(x))$

To understand this, note that an existential can be seen as kind of disjunction, that is, if $a,b,c,...$ denote the objects in your domain, then you can think of an existential like this:

$\exists x \varphi(x) \approx \varphi(a) \lor \varphi(b) \lor \varphi(c) \lor ...$

Now, this is certainly *not* an official equivalence, as I am really mixing semantics and syntax here, but again, it serves to at least conceptuall understand why we can bring out an existential over a conjunct if that conjunct does not contain the relevant free variable, because we now get:

$\psi \land \exists x \varphi(x) \approx \psi \land (\varphi(a) \lor \varphi(b) \lor \varphi(c) \lor ....) \Leftrightarrow (\psi \land \varphi(a)) \lor (\psi \land \varphi(b)) \lor (\psi \land \varphi(c)) \lor ...  \approx \exists x (\psi \land \varphi(x))$

Applying these two principles to your statement, we get:

$\exists z \in Z \exists y \in Y (P_1(x,y) \land P_2(y,z) \land P_3(z,w)) \Leftrightarrow$ (use principle 1)

$\exists y \in Y \exists z \in Z (P_1(x,y) \land P_2(y,z) \land P_3(z,w)) \Leftrightarrow$ (use principle 2)

$\exists y\in Y (P_1(x,y) \land \exists z (P_2(y,z) \land P_3(z,w)))$

**Addendum**

In response to a comment below by EE18: Yes, you can use the 'expansion method' used in 2) above to show a number of other equivalences. To do that, we'll use:

$\forall x \ \varphi(x) \approx \varphi(a) \land \varphi(b) \land \varphi(c) \land ...$

Now we can do:

3. Null Quantification:

3A) $\exists x \ \psi \Leftrightarrow \psi$

'Proof': $\exists x \ \psi \approx \psi \lor \psi \lor \psi ...\Leftrightarrow \psi$ (we get one entry of $\psi$ for each object in the domain, and because in classical logic we assume there is always at least one object in any domain, we get one or more $\psi$ terms that by Idempotence collapse into exactly one)

3B) $\forall x \ \psi \Leftrightarrow \psi$

'Proof': $\forall x \ \psi \approx \psi \land \psi \land \psi ...\Leftrightarrow \psi$ (we get one entry of $\psi$ for each object in the domain, and because in classical logic we assume there is always at least one object in any domain, we get one or more $\psi$ terms that by Idempotence collapse into exactly one)

4A) Distribution of $\exists$ over $\lor$:

$\exists x (\psi(x) \lor \varphi(x)) \Leftrightarrow \exists x \psi(x) \lor \exists \varphi(x) $

(where $\psi(x)$ is *any* formula (so that may or may not contain a free variable $x$)

'Proof':

$\exists x (\psi(x) \lor \varphi(x)) \approx (\psi(a) \lor \varphi(a)) \lor (\psi(b) \lor \varphi(b)) \lor (\psi(c) \lor \varphi(c)) ... \Leftrightarrow (\psi(a) \lor \psi(b) \lor \psi(c)...) \lor (\varphi(a) \lor \varphi(b) \lor \varphi(c) ...| \approx \exists x \ \psi(x) \lor \exists x \ \varphi(x) $

4B) Distribution of $\forall$ over $\land$:

$\forall x (\psi(x) \land \varphi(x)) \Leftrightarrow \forall x \ \psi(x) \land \forall x \ \varphi(x)$ (where $\psi(x)$ is *any* formula (so that may or may not contain a free variable $x$)

'Proof':

$\forall x (\psi(x) \land \varphi(x)) \approx (\psi(a) \land \varphi(a)) \land (\psi(b) \land \varphi(b)) \land (\psi(c) \land \varphi(c)) ... \Leftrightarrow (\psi(a) \land \psi(b) \land \psi(c)...) \land (\varphi(a) \land \varphi(b) \land \varphi(c) ...| \approx \forall x \ \psi(x) \land \forall x \ \varphi(x) $

With these, we can show some other things:

5A) Prenex Law $\exists$ over $\lor$:

$ \exists x (\psi \lor \varphi(x)) \Leftrightarrow \psi \lor \exists x \varphi(x)$

Proof:

$ \exists x (\psi \lor \varphi(x)) \Leftrightarrow \exists x \psi \lor \exists x \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \psi \lor \exists x \varphi(x)$

5B) Prenex Law $\forall$ over $\land$:

$ \forall x (\psi \land \varphi(x)) \Leftrightarrow \psi \land \forall x \varphi(x)$

Proof:

$ \forall x (\psi \land \varphi(x)) \Leftrightarrow \forall x \psi \land \forall x \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \psi \land \forall x \varphi(x)$

Of course, we could have shown 5A) and 5B) using the expansion method as well. (left as exercise to reader)

OK, couple more:

5C) Prenex Law $\exists$ over $\land$:

$ \exists x (\psi \land \varphi(x)) \Leftrightarrow \psi \land \exists x \varphi(x)$

'Proof':

$ \exists x (\psi \land \varphi(x)) \approx (\psi \land \varphi(a)) \lor (\psi \land \varphi(b)) \lor ... \Leftrightarrow \psi \land (\varphi(a) \lor \varphi(b) \lor ...) \approx \psi \land \exists x \ \varphi(x)$

(note, this is the same as 2) above .. but in reverse)

5D) Prenex Law $\forall$ over $\lor$:

$\forall x (\psi \lor \varphi(x)) \Leftrightarrow  \psi \lor \forall x \ \varphi(x) $

'Proof':

$ \forall x (\psi \lor \varphi(x)) \approx (\psi \lor \varphi(a)) \land (\psi \lor \varphi(b)) \land ... \Leftrightarrow \psi \lor (\varphi(a) \land \varphi(b) \land ...) \approx \psi \lor \forall x \ \varphi(x)$

And finally, with these principles, we can now also show that while we are not allowed to swap neighboring $\forall$ and $\exists$ in sentences, we *can* if the quantified variables do not 'interact'. For example:

$\forall x \exists y (\psi(x) \lor \varphi(y)) \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\psi(x) \lor \exists y \ \varphi(y)) \Leftrightarrow \forall x \ \psi(x) \lor \exists y \ \varphi(y) \Leftrightarrow \exists y (\forall x \ \psi(x) \lor  \varphi(y)) \Leftrightarrow \exists y \forall x ( \psi(x) \lor  \varphi(y))$

Comment: Can one generally pull the same trick as your Principle 2 when a $\forall$ is at play? That is, can I "factor out" as in $\forall x : (E(x) \land \varphi) \iff (\forall x : (E(x)) \land \varphi$, and does it matter if it's an $\land$ and/or an $\lor$?

Comment: @EE18 Yes , it works analogously with a $\forall$.

Comment: I can factor out $\forall$ or $\exists$ out of $\land$ and/or $\lor$ with no problem? Surely one of those can't be allowed (I ask because otherwise I'll have a question about "order of operations" to post here, and it seems in your answer we only discuss the particular pair $(\exists, \land)$)?

Comment: (If you get the chance, I tried to summarize my concerns above in an example [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4768026/proving-a-basic-fact-exclusively-using-logic-notation ] here. Thank you again for this really helpful answer!)

Comment: @EE18  I'm just glancing at your post here, but I noticed your last comment. Yes, in general you cannot say that $\exists x \forall x' \phi(x,x')$ (where $\phi(x,x')$ is some formula involving $x$ and $x'$) is equivalent to $\forall x' \exists x \phi(x,x')$, but as you suspected, as long as $x$ and $x'$ don't 'interact', it turns out they are. ... (cont'd)

Comment: @EE18 For example, if the formula $\phi(x,x')$ is something like  $\phi(x) \land \phi'(x')$, then you can do $\exists x \forall x' \phi(x,x') = \exists x \forall x' (\phi(x) \land \phi'(x')) = \exists x (\phi(x) \land \forall x' \phi'(x')) = \exists x \phi(x) \land \forall x' \phi'(x') = \forall x' (\exists x \phi(x) \land  \phi'(x')) = \forall x' \exists x (\phi(x) \land  \phi'(x')) = \forall x' \exists x  \phi(x,x')$

Comment: Thank you, that helps me a great deal here. I guess the last thing I need to figure out in that particular problem is how exactly one sets $x' = x$ and gets the "cancellation".