# Can the order of adjacent and same quantifiers be mixed?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

So can we mix say $\forall x \forall y$ to $\forall y \forall x$ or $\exists y \exists x$ to $\exists x \exists y$ for any possible predicate? And in general, could you mix the order of quantifiers up to a differing quantifier, so $\forall x \exists y \exists z$ could be changed to $\forall x \exists z \exists y$?

Comment: Yes to all questions, unless there is a subtle logical issue regarding "any possible predicate". See [Quantifiers and properties, why and when do they "commute"? An elementary perpective of "non logician"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2053240/13130). Incidentally, your last question is probably not sufficiently addressed explicitly in discussions of quantifiers, but it follows by $(\forall x \exists y \exists z)(P(x,y,z))$ as essentially meaning $(\forall x)((\exists y)((\exists z) (P(x,y,z))))$ (assuming I haven't messed up the parentheses assignments).

Comment: Thus it's YES to your last question because $\forall x \exists y \exists z$ applied to $P(x,y,z)$ is essentially the same as $\forall x$ applied to $(\exists y \exists z)(P(x,y,z)),$ which in turn is essentially the same as $\forall x$ applied to $(\exists z \exists y)(P(x,y,z)).$ What does "essentially the same as" mean? Whatever it needs to be! I'm covering my back because I'm not a logician, and there's probably some subtle logical distinction involved, but if so, I doubt it's anything that matters at the level you're considering this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, quantifiers of the same type are commutative:

$$\forall u \forall v \phi \equiv \forall v \forall u \phi \text{ and }\exists u \exists v \phi \equiv \exists v \exists u \phi$$

for all variables $u, v$ and formulas $\phi$.

If two subformulas are logically equivalent, so are all formulas they occur in, so $\forall x \exists y \exists z \phi \equiv \forall x \exists z \exists y \phi$ also.

However, $\forall$ and $\exists$ are not commutative with each other: $$\exists v \forall u \phi \vDash \forall u \exists v \phi$$ but $$\forall u \exists v \phi \not \vDash \exists v \forall u \phi$$ i.e., whenever $\exists v \forall u \phi$ is true so is $\forall u \exists v \phi$, but not vice versa.

---

The proof comes down to the fact the variable assignments and quantification over them can be swapped on the meta level:

First observe that for a variable assignment $v$ and two objects $a, b$, $$v'' = v[x \mapsto a][y \mapsto b] = v[y \mapsto b][x \mapsto a] = v'$$ -- for two distinct variables $x$ and $y$, it doesn't matter in which order we compute the assignment modifications. Then:

$\newcommand{\A}{\mathfrak{A}}
\begin{align*}
& \A \models_v \forall x \forall y \phi\\
\iff & \text{for all $x$-variants $v'$ of $v$ : } \A \models_{v'} \forall y \phi\\
\iff & \text{for all $x$-variants $v'$ of $v$ and all $y$-variants $v''$ of $v'$: } \A \models_{v''} \phi\\
\iff & \text{for all  $y$-variants $v''$ of $v'$ and all $x$-variants $v'$ of $v$: } \A \models_{v'} \phi\\
\iff & \text{for all $y$-variants $v''$ of $v'$ : } \A \models_{v''} \forall x \phi\\
\iff & \A \models_v \forall y \forall x \phi
\end{align*}$

The middle step is justified because we can swap the two "all"s in the meta language (English) -- becaue that's just how the meaning of "all" works.

Analogous for the commutativity of existence.

Comment: How does one approach a proof like "Show that quantifiers are commutative"? At first-order logic level everything starts to be so abstract, for a good reason, that at best I can try to see why a particular sentence does not hold by a counter example. But I have no idea how to show that something would hold in all possible instances.

Comment: @Qwaster See my edit.