# Proving a basic fact exclusively using "logic notation"

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-writing

I am trying to practice my ability to manipulate the basic logic elements and so am proving the following basic fact:

> Let $f: X \to Y$. Then $A \subseteq X \implies f(X) \setminus f(A) \subseteq f(A^c)$.

My attempt is as follows:

> We have
> $$[y \in f(X) \setminus f(A))] \iff [(y \in f(X)) \land (y \notin f(A))] $$
> $$\iff  [(\exists x: (x \in X)\land (y = f(x))) \land (\neg(\exists x' : (x' \in A)\land (y = f(x'))))]$$
> $$\iff [(\exists x:(x \in X)\land(y = f(x))) \land (\forall x' : (x' \notin A)\lor (y \neq f(x')))]$$
> $$\stackrel{(1)}{\iff} [\exists x: ((x \in X)\land(y = f(x))) \land (\forall x' : (x' \notin A)\lor (y \neq f(x')))]$$
> $$ \stackrel{(2)}{\implies} [\exists x: (x \in X) \land (x \notin A)\land(y = f(x))] \iff [\exists x: (x \in A^c)\land(y = f(x))]  \iff y \in f(A^c)$$
> where in (1) we've used that $\exists$ factors out of a conjunction, in (2) we use that since $f(x) = y$ is true -- or $y \neq f(x)$ false -- for $x ' = x$ we must have from the truth of $(x \notin A)\lor (y \neq f(x))$ that $(x \notin A)$ is true.

I have based some of these manipulations off of the lovely answer in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053240/quantifiers-and-properties-why-and-when-do-they-commute-an-elementary-perpec). However, I am concerned about my step marked (2). I wanted to use just the basic rules of logic, but I have instead "reasoned" like a mathematician. How should I proceed? I have a sneaking suspicion that perhaps I can actually factor out both the $\forall x'$ and the $\exists x$ because the two quantified variables do not "interact" in any of the subsequent formulas, but I am not sure. That is, can I argue as follows?

> We have
> $$[y \in f(X) \setminus f(A))] \iff [(y \in f(X)) \land (y \notin f(A))] $$
> $$\iff  [(\exists x: (x \in X)\land (y = f(x))) \land (\neg(\exists x' : (x' \in A)\land (y = f(x'))))]$$
> $$\iff [(\exists x:(x \in X)\land(y = f(x))) \land (\forall x' : (x' \notin A)\lor (y \neq f(x')))]$$
> $$\stackrel{(1)}{\iff} [\exists x: ((x \in X)\land(y = f(x))) \land (\forall x' : (x' \notin A)\lor (y \neq f(x')))]$$
> $$\stackrel{(2)}{\iff} [\exists x: (\forall x': ((x \in X)\land(y = f(x))) \land ((x' \notin A)\lor (y \neq f(x')))]$$
> $$\iff  [\exists x: (\forall x' : ((x \in X)\land(y = f(x)) \land (x' \notin A)) \lor ((x \in X)\land(y = f(x)) \land (y \neq f(x')))]$$
> $$\stackrel{(3)}{\iff}  [\exists x: (\forall x' : ((x \in X)\land(y = f(x)) \land (x' \notin A))]$$
> $$ \stackrel{(4)}{\implies} [\exists x: (x \in X) \land (x \notin A)\land(y = f(x))] \iff [\exists x: (x \in A^c)\land(y = f(x))]  \iff y \in f(A^c)$$
> where in (2) I've now factored out a $\forall x'$, in (3) I've used that the second statement is always false, and in (4) I've used that if it's true for all $x'$ then it's true for $x$ in particular.

But this answer doesn't feel write because I could have factored out $\forall x'$ *before* $\exists x$, and I thought one couldn't exchange the order of these arbitrarily (or perhaps one can if the formula's involving $x,x'$ don't "interact")?

Comment: Is $f$ known to be surjective? If not, $(f(A))^c = Y \setminus f(A)$, not $f(X) \setminus f(A)$.

Comment: This is just a statement about containg ($\subseteq$), not equality though? Unless the book misprinted something. I suppose I should have tried to prove it out "normally" first. @MatthewLeingang

Comment: Let $X$ and $Y$ be the set of integers, and $f(x) = 2x$. Let $A$ be the set of even integers. What are $f(A)^c$ and $f(A^c)$?

Comment: Oof, I made a big error. Let me edit -- apologies, and thank you for the clarification. @MatthewLeingang The statement has now been amended (also to reflect that which has been proven).

Comment: Aha, that makes more sense. What is "the second statement" in (3) that you say is always false? I'm not following.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang The second statement is everything after the $\lor$, i.e. the contradiction $((x \in X)\land(y = f(x)) \land (y \neq f(x')))$. But now that I think about it, maybe I have to set $x = x'$ before using that this is a contradiction?

Comment: Yeah I don't think that's a contradiction. Up to there is makes sense. $f(X) \setminus f(A)$ is the set of all $f(x)$ which are not equal to $f(a)$ for any $a \in A$.

Comment: Totally agree, but then would you be able to comment on how I can keep going here? I'm stuck if that step isn't valid. @MatthewLeingang

Comment: I think you can skip step (3) entirely. After step (2), set $x' = x$.

Comment: And can you explain rigorously what "setting $x = x'$ means? Does that mean using that, in general, $[\forall x' : E(x')] \implies E(x)$ for a specific $x \in X$ (and $E$ some formula)? I guess this is naive but I just want to know precisely which rules of inference I'm using. @MatthewLeingang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, so far,
$$
    f(X) \setminus f(A)
    = \left\{y \mid \exists x,\ \forall x',\ (x \in X) \land (y = f(x)) \land ((x'\notin A) \lor (y \neq f(x'))
\right\}
$$
Now set $x' = x$, and you get that $f(X) \setminus f(A)$ is contained in the set
$$
\left\{y \mid \exists x,\ (x \in X) \land (y = f(x)) \land ((x\notin A) \lor (y \neq f(x))
\right\}
$$
Use the distributive law:
$$\begin{aligned}
(x \in X) \land (y = f(x)) \land ((x\notin A) \lor (y \neq f(x))
&= ((x \in X) \land (y = f(x)) \land (x \notin A)
\\&\quad\lor ((x \in X) \land \color{red}{(y = f(x)) \land (y \neq f(x)})
\end{aligned}$$
The red part simplifies to FALSE, which means that half of the $\land$ expression evaluates to FALSE, and we leave it off. We have
$$
    (x \in X) \land (x \notin A) \land (y=f(x))
$$
Which means that $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in X \setminus A$.

Comment: Thank you! The "is contained bit" is I suppose where you use that fixing a particular value from a $\forall$ quantifier means that you only get a one way implication, like I mentioned in the comment above?